# String searching output tranformated into rows

Tags: t-sql

I would greatly appreciate your help on below.
How starting with Actual Table achieve Desired Table 1 or Desired Table 2.
How to identify next ocurrence with patindex function?

Regards,
Arek

[image]

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: I try to put this in my words: There is a string. The string has fragments, separated by blanks. You want to find all occurences of *number-dot-number-dot-number* . Is this correct?

Comment: Btw: Please tag your question with the full RDBMS-tag (vendor and version). [tsql] points to SQL-Server but this is not the only product on tsql... The version is important, as many functions depend on this...

Answer (score 1):

Some of this is wild guessing... My magic crystal ball told me, that you might be looking for something like this:

I start with a *mock-up* table to simulate your issue.
This is something you should do yourself for your next question. People on SO don't like pictures...

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(TicketID INT,[Text] NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES(1,'here is no fitting pattern at all')
                         ,(2,'one fitting pattern at the end 123.234.345')
                         ,(3,'234.345.456 one fitting pattern at the beginning')
                         ,(4,'one fitting pattern 456.567.678 in the middle')
                         ,(5,'several 987.876.765 fitting 876.756.645 patterns 123.234.345');
```

--The query will use a XML-trick to split your string in fragments.
--Each fragment is checked for exactly two dots and the value without dots must be castable to `BIGINT`.
--This might not be perfect, but SQL-Server is known as rather weak with such actions

```
SELECT t.TicketID
      ,C.Fragment
FROM @mockup t
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(t.[Text],' ','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)) A(Casted)
CROSS APPLY A.Casted.nodes('/x') B(FragmentXml)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT B.FragmentXml.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)')) C(Fragment)
WHERE LEN(C.Fragment)-LEN(REPLACE(C.Fragment,'.',''))=2               --two dots
      AND TRY_CAST(REPLACE(C.Fragment,'.','') AS BIGINT) IS NOT NULL  --a number without dots
```

The result

```
ID  Fragment
2   123.234.345
3   234.345.456
4   456.567.678
5   987.876.765
5   876.756.645
5   123.234.345
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple if you pick up a copy of [patternSplitCM](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/String+Manipulation/94365/). Here' I'm using @shnugo's sample data but I added numbers that, according to my crystal ball, should not be included in the final output.

```
-- sample data
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(TicketID INT,[Text] NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES(1,'here is no fitting pattern at all')
                         ,(2,'one fitting pattern 123 at the end 123.234.345')
                         ,(3,'234.345.456 one fitting pattern at the beginning')
                         ,(4,'one 333 fitting pattern 456.567.678 in the 99.99 middle')
                         ,(5,'several 987.876.765 fitting 876.756.645 patterns 123.234.345');
-- Solution
SELECT      
  Ticket     = m.TicketID, 
  ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY F.Item ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)),
  Item       =  f.Item
FROM        @mockup AS m
CROSS APPLY dbo.PatternSplitCM(m.[Text],'[0-9.]') AS F
WHERE       f.[Matched]=1 -- has numbers and/or dots
AND         LEN(f.item)-LEN(REPLACE(f.item,'.','')) > 1;  -- has numbers after removing 1+ dots
```

**Returns:**

```
Ticket      ItemNumber           Item
----------- -------------------- ------------
2           1                    123.234.345
5           2                    123.234.345
3           1                    234.345.456
4           1                    456.567.678
5           1                    876.756.645
5           1                    987.876.765
```